# Multiple Express with express-session Applications on Single Server, Different Ports

Tags: session, express, express-session

I am running multiple MEAN applications using express-session on a single server under multiple ports. When I authenticate into application A, the established token for the other (application B) is modified. The authenticated user session for application B is then denied.

How do I configure all of my applications to persist and verify tokens independently? For example, on localhost, application A runs on port 80, and application B runs on port 90. I want a user to be able to authenticate and use application A without disrupting another user's Application B session.

Here is the code in my app.js file that should be relevant to my issue:

```
// Connect to database
mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);

var connection = mongoose.createConnection(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);

var app = express();

// enable CORS
app.use(cors());

// enable cookieParser
app.use(cookieParser());

// enable session
app.use(session({
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    name: 'uniqueSessionId',
    store: new MongoStore(
        {
            mongooseConnection: connection
        }
    )
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Cookies (which are used to store the session identifier in) are shared across all ports on a given hostname, which is why your apps are interfering with each other.

The documentation of [`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#name) suggests the following:

> if you have multiple apps running on the same hostname (this is just the name, i.e. `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`; different schemes and ports do not name a different hostname), then you need to separate the session cookies from each other. The simplest method is to simply set different `name`s per app.

Comment: Per the documentation, I tried modifying my session object by including a unique name, but it didn't work. The two applications are still interfering with one another.

Comment: Did you remove the old cookies too?

Comment: Yes, I see the new names of the application cookies, and a cookie named "token." I'm wondering if there should be a token cookie for each application instead of one? It seems to me that the token cookie is the one that keeps getting modified by each application.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Are you mixing jwt's with session cookies or something?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm using Passport with LocalStrategy to manage authentication for each application. I don't know if I can set an application-specific token as a cookie that is not named "token." As I monitor logins for each application, I check the "token" in the browser, and it gets overwritten each time.

Comment: Passport shouldn't be setting that cookie by itself, AFAIK it'll just use `req.session` (so it depends entirely on `express.session()`, which is setting differently named cookies for each app now). Perhaps grep for `token` in your code to see what is setting it (might also be done client-side).